# d3 custom time interval

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The following code rounds up a data series and sums up amounts with a minute interval.

```
   var nested_data = d3.nest()
   .key(function(d) {return d3.time.minute(d.date)})
   .rollup(function(a) {return d3.sum(a, function(d) {return d.amount})})
   .entries(data);
```

However, is there a way to have a custom interval of say 5 minutes? Perhaps using a range with a step ?

Comment: I don't use D3, but its just Javascript. Have you tried making the key function `return Math.floor(d3.time.minute(d.date)/5)` ?

Comment: Thank you for replying! Just tried that, but it just seems to then convert the dates to 1978, and they are no longer rounded. This page describes the d3.time interval function, https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals , but I can't seem to work out how to use the step aspect to create a custom interval.

Comment: Be careful where the parenthesis go.  `Math.floor` will only return integers.  If you divide a current date by 5, it will wind up in 1978, because dates have an integer representation as ms since 1970. But the suggestion divides the minutes by 5 not the date.

Comment: I think d3.time.minute(d.date) returns the date, for example: console.log(d3.time.minute(d.date)), this returns Sun May 11 2014 11:43:00 GMT+0100 (BST)

Comment: Think I managed to fudge it, would be nice to use the internal d3 functions though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to do it:

```
  var coeff = 1000 * 60 * 5;
   var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return new Date(Math.round(d.date.getTime() / coeff) * coeff)})
  .rollup(function(a) {return d3.sum(a, function(d) {return d.amount})})
  .entries(data);
```